# PHP Excel return false to string with special chars

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have several strings from a form (`$_POST` var), some of them with special chars (ñ, á, é, etc.). When I create the Excel file with these `$_POST` vars, all cells print the right information but the ones with special chars prints `FALSE`.

Here's a piece of  code:

```
for ($j=1; $j<$_POST["z"]; $j++) {
$fila_despacho = $j+1;  
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
->setCellValue('A'.$fila_despacho, '03') 
->setCellValue('B'.$fila_despacho, $_POST["servicio".$j])
->setCellValue('C'.$fila_despacho, trim ($_POST["comuna".$j]))
->setCellValue('D'.$fila_despacho, 1)
->setCellValue('E'.$fila_despacho, trim($_POST["nombre".$j]))
->setCellValue('F'.$fila_despacho, trim($_POST["direccion".$j]))
        ->setCellValue('G'.$fila_despacho, trim($_POST["num".$j]));    
}//endfor
```

About UTF-8, I don't know how to check that, I'm new at this. Can you tell me how?

Comment: Can you post a bit of code?

Comment: Are you using UTF-8?

Answer (score 5):

Change to UTF-8 before setting the cell value. Use `utf8_encode()`. Example:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', utf8_encode($descripcion));
```

Later on you can save the file, for example with:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;  charset=UTF-8');  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='$archivo'");
```

Comment: What to do if i just want to save the file not to download it in brawser ?